# eclipse cdt debug Variables can't show float(e.g float a = 2.0)

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

when I debug it.
Eclipse cdt Variables show "i" is 2 but 2.0000000.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float i = 2.0;
    float j = 2.1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want the debugger to show the full precision with all decimals even when it's not needed?

Comment: At first, I think this is an Eclipse'bug. I 'so sorry!